# Add file to available torrent application in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, file-browser, android-actionmode

I want to add my torrent file on sd card to installed torrent applications (uTorrent, BitTorrent). I have made my own File picker activity in which I am showing files. when user click on any file then if more than 1 torrent application installed then show suggestion otherwise add in available torrent application.

Everything works fine. It show suggestion when more than 1 application installed and also launch available application when only 1 torrent supported application installed. But problem is when application launch it shows "Failed to add "Path of file"".

Below is my code.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
File file123 = new File(seleFile.getAbsolutePath());
MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file123.getName());
String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
Uri data = Uri.fromFile(file123);
i.setDataAndType(data, type);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Application"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your "/" in the selected file path. It must be correct because some time we add this in our file name (root path + file Name). And last "/" in root path. Sometimes it will become like below.

```
File seleFile = new File(curPath + seleFileName);
```

And it will become /mnt/sdcard/FolderFilename which is wrong. Use this:

```
File seleFile = new File(curPath + "/" +seleFileName);
```

So it will become /mnt/sdcard/Folder/Filename which is right.